# Is Uber currently safe to use around Cabo San Lucas?

Tags: safety, mexico, uber, los-cabos

I'm a big fan of Uber and use it as much as I can, however some reports on TripAdvisor mention that Uber drivers are being harassed by the taxi mafia. How big is the danger currently in practice? Is it mostly a threat to the drivers or have some passengers been harmed as well?

Comment: I don't live in/near Cabo, but in other parts of Mexico this is a real danger to both drivers and passengers.  In some parts the drivers will ask passengers to sit in the front so it doesn't like so much like you're a paying passenger.  That said, my family, friends, and I have used Uber often in Mexico without any issues.  The bigger issue for us is that where we live Uber is actually illegal as the mayor apparently outlawed it (since they own a taxi company)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Uber for the past few days and it works great. I've also talked to the drivers in my admittedly limited Spanish and none of them reported any safety concerns. Also talked to other tourists and none of them had issues using Uber.

So the answer as of December 2019 is that it's perfectly safe to use. Although do note that it officially remains unlicensed within the state of Baja California Sur, similar to many other jurisdictions where Uber operates semi-illicitly.